# AWS DynamoDB index attribute with multiple type

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table look like this

```
account_id      email               deactivation_date           deleted_on
1               test1@test.com      2018-09-26T16:28:41.143Z    NULL
2               test2@test.com      2018-09-19T16:28:41.143Z    2018-09-19T16:28:41.143Z
```

I'm using AWS CLI to populate the test data, as it shown, deleted_on field will be null or have a string, if it has been deactivated.

I'm using cloudformation template to build the index but it keep failing.
I'd like to put an index on deactivation_date, such that I can query
retrieve all account where

`deactivation_date < tomorrow, and deleted_on is null`

This is my cft

```
  AttributeDefinitions:        
    - AttributeName: "account_id"
      AttributeType: "S"     
    - AttributeName: "email"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "deactivation_date"
      AttributeType: "S"          
  KeySchema:
    -
      AttributeName: "account_id"
      KeyType: "HASH"
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:     
    - IndexName: "email-index"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "email"
          KeyType: "HASH"
      Projection:
        ProjectionType: "ALL"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !If [conditionIsProd, 10, 5]
        WriteCapacityUnits: !If [conditionIsProd, 10, 5]  
    - IndexName: "deactivation_date-index"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "deactivation_date"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      Projection:
        ProjectionType: "ALL"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !If [conditionIsProd, 10, 5]
        WriteCapacityUnits: !If [conditionIsProd, 10, 5]
```

It keeps complaining about

Invalid KeySchema: The first KeySchemaElement is not a HASH key type (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxxxxxx)

and if I put deleted_on as index,
such as

```
- AttributeName: "deleted_on"
  AttributeType: "S"
```

It will complain because I tried to insert NULL, but if I do this

```
- AttributeName: "deleted_on"
  AttributeType: NULL
```

It will also complain I tried to add string.

I'm not sure what's the right way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Global Secondary Index must always have a hash key - you are only defining a range key, which is why you get the 'first KeySchemaElement is not a HASH key type' error.

Second you cannot put a null or empty value in any primary key fields.

In any event you won't be able to run the query you want to even if you setup the hash and range keys properly. The reason is you must always specify an exact hash key when performing a DynamoDB query. So 'deactivation_date < tomorrow' will not work.

If you can provide some more information on what you are trying to accomplish with this, might be able to provide a better table design